# What's the difference between '<S-p>' and 'P' when mapping?

Tags: vim

I want to add a map to switch buffer quickly. I prefer to use 'Shift+p', but I torn between `<S-p>`and `P`.

I have tried both and they all worked fine. I don't know if there has any differences between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no difference.

Vim receives its input from the terminal, not directly from the keyboard. The terminal does a bunch of translating before passing keyboard inputs to other applications. For instance, hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> will send the same ASCII byte (try using `Ctrl+[` in place of `Esc`, it'll be functionally identical).

Likewise, the terminal won't tell any applications when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed; it'll only tell the application if you type a lowercase or uppercase letter. Vim gives you the option of specifying either way, via `<S-P>` or `P`.

For example, set your bind with `<S-p>` and then use caps lock to hit <kbd>P</kbd>. You'll still trigger the bind, because Vim doesn't (and can't) know how you entered `P`, just that you sent a capital `P` to it.

Comment: I tried capslock first, and then hit p. The behavior sure enough as you said! I think it's better to do something only in one way, I mean the `<S-p>` form seems redundant.